# How much of fusion energy is positron-electron annihilation?

Tags: antimatter, fusion

Stellar fusion involves protons becoming neutrons, which means ejecting a positron. Positrons annihilate electrons. This must deliver some energy in stellar fusion. But how much of the energy from stellar fusion comes from this positron-electron annhilation?

Comment: The relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction#The_pp_chain_reaction) states that the position-electron annihilation produces 1.02 MeV of energy.

Comment: Wich kind of fusion are you referring to?

Comment: @lemon that's not the question at hand.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you clarify precisely what the question is?

Comment: Well, if you know the rate of  proton --> neutron + positron reaction, then you just multiply the rate by the volume by twice the electron rest mass (0.5MeV).  But if you want to know how the proton decay compares with all the other reactions, that's a tougher question.

Comment: @lemon.  I'm hoping English isn't your native language or I'll really be sad.  The OP clearly asked for the fraction of all released energy attributable to proton decay.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If you're going to be rude you should at least be right. Where does it say 'fraction'? He simply asks 'how much', which is an ill-defined question. The answer also depends on the star/type. So it's not possible to give a more complete answer than mine without further information.

Comment: You're not entirely correct, either one. Yes, I do mean a fraction (I think more in percentages, but tomato/tomato). However, it's not the proton decay itself, but the positron-electron annihilation that interests me. Please be nice to each other.

Comment: @descheleschilder What kind are you refering to? I meant the fusion reaction inside stars. I was not aware that there are different kinds?

Comment: @Henry Stone I assume you mean the fusion to helium of two deuterium nuclei. And don´t we talk about neutron decay instead of proton decay?

Comment: @ Henry Stone In fact, there can occur many kinds of fusion in stars. That´s where the elements have come (and keep coming) from.

Comment: @Henry Stone Protons have such a long lifetime that we say it doesn´t decay (in the rishon model of Haïm Harari it´s possible in a very simple way (rearrangement of the rishons), though the chance of this happening is very small (the cross section of this scattering process  is very small).

Comment: @lemon Last response , let's kill this.   OP states  "how much  **of**..." which in American English has only one meaning: a fractional part.    To Henry: every positron is annihilated pretty quickly,so there's a one-to-one correspondence between the proton reaction and the $p^+ -- e^- $ reaction

Comment: @descheleschilder Proton decay only. Proton-proton fusion causes a proton to decay, creating a positron; for roughly every two protons involved in fusion, I would assume one decays into a neutron and releases a positron, which should make a fairly large number. That's where the bulk of the deuterium comes from, AFAIK. I am not talking about spontaneous proton decay, which I honestly thought did not happen on any relevant scale, anywhere.

Comment: @Carl Okay, I get the decay vs. annihilation angle now. But as I see it, there are more factors involved than those, right? The fusion of deuterium and other non-proton-decaying reactions would account for a significant amount of energy, I assume. I can only find bits and pieces of information on it, not enough to put together a grander picture...

Comment: @Henry Stone But in a helium nucleus, the product of the fusion there are two protons. Neutrons decay, protons don´t. And is deuterium really the product of a helium nucleus? Why should the fact that two protons are bound together by the strong force make one of them decay into a positron and a meson? And considering the energy: the energy of two bound protons is minimal, so how can this state turn into a state with a higher energy? I think you confuse neutron decay (wich gives a neutrino and a meson) with proton decay.